# Text file not displaying properly on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Flask web App)

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, web-applications

I have created a machine learning web app and I converted the dataframe predictions into a .txt file that users can download

```
df.to_csv('pred.txt', sep=',', index=False)
```

and the output format should be like (on localhost Windows 10):

```
x,y,z
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

However, when I deployed my web app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (linux) and download the pred.txt, the format became like:

```
x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Why is the format like that and how should I change it so that the format is like the the prior format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows and Linux have different newline characters:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

You can force `to_csv()` to use the Windows newlines by providing it as `line_terminator`, like so:

`df.to_csv('pred.txt', sep=',', index=False, line_terminator='\r\n')`